# Como atualizar o canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Em um canvas, adicionei 10 pequenos quadrados, mas quero também poder alterar a posição desses quadrados continuamente, e que essa alteração seja desenhada na tela sempre quando o fizer (não preciso necessariamente de uma animação, apenas entender como posso atualizar o canvas sempre que quiser). Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem a dúvida, mas você precisa redesenhar tudo a cada quadro. Uma vez desenhado um objeto, não tem como movê-lo.

Comment: @bfavaretto ...entetanto você pode copiar elementos imutáveis (tipo um background) para um outro canvas que você pode utilizar como buffer - sem necessidade de re-gerar todos os elementos de novo. (`context.drawImage(oldCanvas, 0, 0);`)

Comment: @OnoSendai Isso tem muita vantagem de performance em relação a chamar uma função que gera um layer?

Comment: @bfavaretto depende da complexidade e do número de objetos estáticos - minha experiência é que essa técnica pode ser uma mão na roda

Comment: Legal, vou testar quando precisar disso. @OnoSendai

Answer (score 0):

Use o `context.clearRect` para limpar o `canvas` ou apenas o quadrado. E então redesenhe.

Answer (score -1):

Para apagar você usa o `context.clearRect(width,height);`, para desenhar você usa o `context.drawImage(imagem,x,y);`.